# Pydantic: How to init a model by a dict with alias field names?

Tags: python-3.x, pydantic

I have a model:

```
class Cars(BaseModel):
 numberOfCars: int = Field(0,alias='Number of cars')
```

I have a dict with:

```
{
"Number of cars":3
}
```

How can I create an instance of Cars by using this model?`
Is there something like 'by_alias' when using this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should definitely start by reading the [Pydantic Documentation](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io)

Here is a working example:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class Cars(BaseModel):
    numberOfCars: int = Field(0, alias='Number of cars')


def main():
    car_dict = {'Number of cars': 4}
    cars = Cars(**car_dict)
    print(cars)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thx. My example was far more complicated and I've the wrong model.